# Show that $\langle S\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $S$ is a subset of a group $G$, and $gsg^{-1} \in S$ for each $s \in S$ and $g \in G$. Show that $\langle S\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I am stuck on this problem. Is anyone is able to give me a hint?

Comment: What definition(s) of $\langle S\rangle$ do you know? What about "normal subgroup of $G$"?

Comment: I know the typic definition of $\langle S \rangle$ and the normal subgroup de $G$. I try to prove that $g^*s(g^*)^{-1} \in S$, but how to use the particular $g$?

Comment: Did you notice that the two answer used two **different** definitions of $\langle S\rangle$? There are *multiple* common (equivalent) definitions of $\langle S\rangle$ and of "normal subgroup," which is the reason I asked.

Comment: I know both definitions. I still don't understand how to do this.

Comment: *What definitions do you know*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $\langle S \rangle$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by all products of $s \in S$ and their inverses. Note that for $s_1, s_2$ and a particular $g$ in $G$, we have $s_1s_2 = s_1g^{-1}gs_2$.

Comment: Could you explain to me a bit more?

Comment: Well, suppose we have some element $s \in \langle S \rangle$. Here $s = s_1s_2\dots s_n$ where all $s_i$ are in $S$. We want to show $\langle S \rangle$ is normal, that is, for any $s \in \langle S \rangle$ and $g \in G$ we also have $gsg^{-1} \in \langle S \rangle$. And then...?

Answer (score 1):

Here is slightly different approach which uses the characterization that $\langle S \rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains $S$. In other words, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $S \subseteq H$, then $\langle S \rangle \subseteq H$.

Let $gSg^{-1}$ denote the set $\{gsg^{-1} \mid s \in S\}$. We are given that $gSg^{-1} \subseteq S$, or equivalently $S \subseteq g^{-1}Sg$, for every $g \in G$.

Now, since $S \subseteq \langle S \rangle$, we have $S \subseteq g^{-1}Sg \subseteq g^{-1}\langle S \rangle g$. This means that $g^{-1}\langle S \rangle g$ is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $S$. But $\langle S \rangle$ is the smallest such subgroup, so $\langle S \rangle \subseteq g^{-1}\langle S \rangle g$. Equivalently, $g\langle S \rangle g^{-1} \subseteq \langle S \rangle$. This holds for every $g \in G$, so $\langle S \rangle \lhd G$.

Comment: $g\langle S \rangle g^{-1} \subseteq \langle S \rangle$ is not covering all $g^{*} \in G$. The normal subgroup ask that $g^* s (g^*)^{-1} \in S$ pour all $g^* \in G$. In our case, there exists $g \in G$ such that $gsg^{-1} \in S$

Comment: Doesn't "for each $s \in S$ and $g \in G$" mean "for each $s \in S$ and for each $g \in G$"?